# Compare two objects apart from one property? php

Tags: php, object, properties, compare

I am trying to compare two objects, to see if they are the same. While doing this, I need to ignore one of the properties.

This is my current code:

```
$exists = array_filter($this->products, function($stored, $key) use ($item) {
    return ($stored == $item);
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

This will compare the objects are the same completely. I need to temporarily remove a property of `quantity` from `$stored`

Comment: `unset($stored->quantity)`

Comment: `return ($key == 'quantity') || ($stored == $item);`

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an array of *objects*, if you `unset` properties from them, it will not unset the properties only in the context of `array_filter`. Because the array contains [object identifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php), it will actually remove the properties from the objects in `$this->products`. If you want to *temporarily* remove a property for comparison, just save a copy of it before unsetting, then do your comparison, then add it back to the object before return the result of the comparison.

```
$exists = array_filter($this->products, function($stored, $key) use ($item) {
    $quantity = $stored->quantity;      // keep it here
    unset($stored->quantity);           // temporarily remove it
    $result = $stored == $item;         // compare
    $stored->quantity = $quantity;      // put it back
    return $result;                     // return
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```

Another possibility is to clone the object and unset the property from the clone. Depending on how complex the object is, this may not be as efficient.

```
$exists = array_filter($this->products, function($stored, $key) use ($item) {
    $temp = clone($stored);
    unset($temp->quantity);
    return $temp == $item;
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_BOTH);
```